# How to pass error message from method causing exception to onTestFailure method in Listener

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports

I am trying to print exception message from method which causing exception to testng listener so that I can print it in extent report. I have written code like this

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    String screenshotPath = "";
    try {
        screenshotPath = ScreenshotUtil.capture();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        test2.log(Status.FAIL, MarkupHelper.createLabel("Error occured", ExtentColor.RED));

        test2.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath, "Error");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and I am throwing exception in below method

```
public HomePage assertLoginSuccessful(boolean flag, String name) throws ExplicitAssertionError, IOException{
        waitForPageToLoad();
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 5);
        String xpath="//a[@id='welcome'][contains(.,'Welcome "+name+"')]";
        try{
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpath)));
        if (flag){
                List<WebElement> list=getDriver().findElements(By.xpath(xpath));

                if (list.size()==0){
                    throw new ExplicitAssertionError("User name"+name+" not found hence login not successful");//this message should be passed to listener
                }
        }
        }catch (Exception ex){
            throw new ExplicitAssertionError("User name"+name+" not found hence login not successful");
        }
        return this;
```

Comment: what is the problem, you are facing?

Comment: I want to pass the error message from java method to testng listener so that error message is printed in report. Is there a parameter in listener method onTestFailure() which can get failure message from failing method. Currently I am just able to attach the screenshot with hard-coded error message

Comment: e.getMessage() can give you exception message,

Comment: I want to pass the message from ExplicitAssertionError constructor to onTestFailure method of listener class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface `ITestResult` contains a method `getThrowable` to access the exception you are throwing in your test.

You can add the following code to `onTestFailure`:

```
    if (null != result.getThrowable()) {
      String msg = result.getThrowable().getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: This is what exactly I wanted. I had known that I would have to use throwable class but was unable to do since I didn't know method. Thanks for letting me know.